# Zend Framework + Uplodify Flash Uploader Troubles

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, zend-framework

I've been trying to get the **Uploadify** flash uploader (www.uploadify.com) to work with Zend Framework, with no success so far.

I have placed all Uploadify files under */public/flash-uploader* directory.

In the controller I include all required files and libraries like this:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/flash-uploader/css/default.css');
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/flash-uploader/css/uploadify.css');
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/flash-uploader/scripts/swfobject.js');
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/flash-uploader/scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js');
```

And then I activate the plugin like this (#photo is id of the input file field):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#photo").uploadify({
    'uploader'       : '/flash-uploader/scripts/uploadify.swf',
    'script'         : 'my-account/flash-upload',
    'cancelImg'      : '/flash-uploader/cancel.png',
    'folder'         : 'uploads/tmp',
    'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
    'auto'           : true,
    'multi'          : true,
        'sizeLimit'      : 2097152
    });
});
```

As you can see I am targeting the my-account/flash-upload script as a backend processing (my-account is a controller, flash-upload is an action).

My form markup looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/my-account/upload-public-photo"><ol>
<li><label for="photo" class="optional">File Queue<div id="fileQueue"></div></label>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="31457280" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" />
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="input-file" /></li>
<li><div class="button">
<input type="submit" name="upload_public_photo" id="upload_public_photo" value="Save" class="input-submit" /></div></li></ol></form>
```

And yet it's not working. The browse button doesn't even show up as in the demo page, I get only a regular input file field.

Any ideas where could the problem be? I've already been staring into the code for hours and I cannot see any mistake anywhere and I'm starting to be exhausted after going through the same 30 lines of code 30 times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

By looking through the demo code and the documentation : it seems that the plugin is providing the 'FORM' elements by itself.

You should try to put your input field outside your form

Never used this tool before, just my 2 cents :)

Comment: That's not the problem, I have tried wrapping the input field in the form in the demo page and ti works there... but it doesn't work in my Zend Framework template that has the same markup...